# char array showing empty trying to append second string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just want to store(append/cancatenate) three mobile numbers in a char array. In a for loop I'm giving three mobile numbers. I wrote a function to store the mobile
numbers. The char array stores the first mobile number by printing the length of the array variable. When I try to store the second mobile number the char array becomes null (length of the array is zero). Actually the variable array "auth_mob_no" index is incremented continuously (`j++`) and to get the second number need to set variable array "mob_no" index to zero (k=0). Why is not storing the strings after I gave the first string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char mob_auth(char mob_no[]);
int i,j=0,k=0;

int main()
{
    char num[15];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",num);
        if(mob_auth(num))
        {
            printf("Mobile Number stored\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char mob_auth(char mob_no[])
{
    char auth_mob_no[50];
    while(mob_no[k]!='\0')
    {
        auth_mob_no[j]=mob_no[k];
        k++;j++;
    }
    auth_mob_no[j]='\0';
    k=0;
    printf("len:%d\n",strlen(auth_mob_no));
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
    input by user: +919999999999
    len:13
    Authicated Mobile Number

    input by user: +918888888888
    len:0
    Authicated Mobile Number
```

Comment: The global variables `i`, `j` and `k` should be local; single character names are a very bad choice for a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auth_mob_no` is automatic variable, so its contents will vanish on exiting its scope (returning from `mob_auth` in this case).

To correct, do either one of these:

- Add `static` before `char auth_mob_no[50]`
- Remove the local variable `auth_mob_no` and make it global like you did for `j` and `k`

Also note that the line `printf("len:%d\n",strlen(auth_mob_no));` will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`.

Use correct format specifier

```
printf("len:%zu\n",strlen(auth_mob_no));
```

or cast the data before passing (because the length will be small enough in this case)

```
printf("len:%d\n",(int)strlen(auth_mob_no));
```